# Scanner.next() taking in more than 1 word in loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am making a game in my java class, and I am trying to ask users what kind of difficulty they want to play. However, it seems that the `IN.next()` is taking in more than 1 word because it is in a loop. How do I get it to take only the first word?

```
public int configureDifficulty() {      
    String level = "1";
    println("At what difficulty would you like to play at?");
    println("Type 1 for easy, 2 for medium, 3 for hard.");

    while (true) {

        level = IN.next();
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(level);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            println("Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

**Console**

```
At what difficulty would you like to play at?
Type 1 for easy, 2 for medium, 3 for hard. 
test test test test test
Try again
Try again
Try again
Try again
Try again
```

How to make my program prints just one "Try Again" line, even if users type more than 1 word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nextLine` method of `Scanner` to read input as `String` and then later convert it like you want. You can do something like this.

```
import java.util.*;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int d = configureDifficulty();

        System.out.println(d);
    }



    public static int configureDifficulty() {

    String level = "1";
    System.out.println("At what difficulty would you like to play at?");
    System.out.println("Type 1 for easy, 2 for medium, 3 for hard.");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

        level = in.nextLine();
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(level);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take care of words typed on the same line, you will have to use `nextLine` method in scanner. The method will return a string and then you will have to parse and write the logic.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to read is an integer `(1,2 or 3)` to determine difficulty, so I suggest you to use `scanner.nextInt()` so that you don't need to do the parsing and the extra `try-catch` block.

Also, you haven't given your complete code(how `scanner` object is initialized and used in other places)  but with whatever you have given, I don't see `next()` consuming more than one character. If it does and you don't want to replace it with `scanner.nextInt()`, use `scanner.nextLine()` instead. Hope this helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String level = "1";
    System.out.println("At what difficulty would you like to play at?");
    System.out.println("Type 1 for easy, 2 for medium, 3 for hard.");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {   
        System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
    }
}
```